# PHPMAiler DKIM signature working in command line (but not in browser)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, dkim

I have just installed PHPMailer 6.1 and managed to send a test e-mail through a simple php file using command line (php my_email_file.php). I was even able to sign it with DKIM so that Gmail flag it as signed by my domain.

However, when I run the very same file through the browser ([www.mydomain.com/my_email_file.php](http://www.mydomain.com/my_email_file.php)), the e-mail is sent but the DKIM signature no longer works. Debug info does not contain any hints, it simply ignores de DKIM part.

I am assuming either php versions are different or there is any permissions issue. I could not validate any of the two hypotheses and could not find any similar questions here or elsewhere.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance.

UPDATING with more details:

For reference, this is the code I am using both in CLI and web (php file located in /var/www/mywebsite/web):

```
<?php
/**
 * This example shows making an SMTP connection without using authentication.
 */

//Import the PHPMailer class into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

$direccion = "xxx@gmail.com";
$titulo = "DKIM Test";
$mensaje = "DKIM signed message";
$replyto = "info@mydomain.com";
$replytoname = "MyName";

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');

require 'new_mail/vendor/autoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// SMTP::DEBUG_OFF = off (for production use)
// SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT = client messages
// SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->setLanguage('es', 'PHPMailer/language');
//We don't need to set this as it's the default value
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'info@mydomain.com';
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('info@mydomain.com', 'MyName');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->AddReplyTo($replyto, $replytoname);
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress($direccion);
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject    = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($titulo)."?=";
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';

//This should be the same as the domain of your From address
$mail->DKIM_domain = 'mydomain.com';
//See the DKIM_gen_keys.phps script for making a key pair -
//here we assume you've already done that.
//Path to your private key:
$mail->DKIM_private = '/var/lib/amavis/dkim/mydomain.com.private';
//Set this to your own selector
$mail->DKIM_selector = 'mail';
//Put your private key's passphrase in here if it has one
$mail->DKIM_passphrase = '';
//The identity you're signing as - usually your From address
$mail->DKIM_identity = $mail->From;
//Suppress listing signed header fields in signature, defaults to true for debugging purpose
$mail->DKIM_copyHeaderFields = false;

$privatekey = $mail->DKIM_private;
echo $privatekey;
if (file_exists($privatekey))
{
    echo "Has access";
}
else
{
    echo "No access";
}

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: '. $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message sent!';
}
```

This is what I get in CLI:

```
Has access
08:05:49       SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 myserver ESMTP
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO myserver
08:05:49     SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-myserver
                                          250-PIPELINING
                                          250-SIZE 20480000
                                          250-ETRN
                                          250-STARTTLS
                                          250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
                                          250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
                                          250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                          250-8BITMIME
                                          250 DSN
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
08:05:49     SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
08:05:49     SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
08:05:49     SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<info@mydomain.com>
08:05:49     SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Ok
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<xxx@gmail.com>
08:05:49     SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Ok
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
08:05:49     SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Sat, 25 Jul 2020 10:05:49 +0200
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: To: xxx@gmail.com
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: From: MyName <info@mydomain.com>
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: Reply-To: MyName <info@mydomain.com>
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: =?UTF-8?B?SG9sYSBES0lN?=
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <FbCdgC7Q8GcnzAXbC81d7aR8dGYXMjaHTPcJufflp1Y@ns300543>
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.1.7 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER:  boundary="b1_FbCdgC7Q8GcnzAXbC81d7aR8dGYXMjaHTPcJufflp1Y"
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: DKIM-Signature: v=1; d=mydomain.com; s=mail;
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER:  a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; t=1595664349; c=relaxed/simple;
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER:  h=Date:To:From:Reply-To:Subject:Message-ID:X-Mailer:MIME-Version:Content-Type;
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER:  i=info@mydomain.com;
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER:  bh=quH/vtvt3pX5+MdRVXNLdXO5/96jjoTSgctYgk2xZJI=;
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER:  b=KLNeiShgq2uE2FkMqDDNuNn4w0C0ZmD9hcuhNMzE07xenka3a+Ech4i7+9+SLnOXTv30H8tq5
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER:  NiUjLCU4c6BsYZxfeD4MH/qKHAD02yzZHfECCj2C3T2HaQb+qbSrzkhAYfYnfRDxNhtPI34sE
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER:  dNHXVb6fL9ptKvv9cIBj0xUEk=
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER:
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER:
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_FbCdgC7Q8GcnzAXbC81d7aR8dGYXMjaHTPcJufflp1Y
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER:
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER:
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_FbCdgC7Q8GcnzAXbC81d7aR8dGYXMjaHTPcJufflp1Y
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER:
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: DKIM test
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER:
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER:
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_FbCdgC7Q8GcnzAXbC81d7aR8dGYXMjaHTPcJufflp1Y--
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER:
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: .
08:05:49     SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 500561A80068
08:05:49     CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
08:05:49     SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

And this one, what I get after running the very same php file through browser

```
No access
08:06:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 myserver ESMTP
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mydomain.com
08:06:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-ns300543.ip-91-121-64.eu250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 20480000250-ETRN250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250 DSN
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
08:06:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
08:06:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
08:06:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<info@mydomain.com>
08:06:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Ok
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<xxx@gmail.com>
08:06:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Ok
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
08:06:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Sat, 25 Jul 2020 10:06:29 +0200
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: xxx@gmail.com
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: MyName <info@mydomain.com>
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: Reply-To: MyName <info@mydomain.com>
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: =?UTF-8?B?SG9sYSBES0lN?=
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <4neYS87UPhdjVyQOEiztiLiXfL6Z0XZZgTPT0tr0@mydomain.com>
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.1.7 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_4neYS87UPhdjVyQOEiztiLiXfL6Z0XZZgTPT0tr0"
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_4neYS87UPhdjVyQOEiztiLiXfL6Z0XZZgTPT0tr0
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_4neYS87UPhdjVyQOEiztiLiXfL6Z0XZZgTPT0tr0
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: DKIM test
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_4neYS87UPhdjVyQOEiztiLiXfL6Z0XZZgTPT0tr0--
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER:
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
08:06:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 725A21A80068
08:06:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
08:06:29 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
Message sent!
```

So, as you can see, the message is sent in both cases and authentication works as well. The key difference is that the instance run through browser does not get access to the private key file and, hence, cannot sign the message, while the CLI one can access and can sign.

Comment: You don't say what you mean by "no longer works"; is it present? DKIM is really tricky and there have been some bugs in PHPMailer relating to it, so make sure you're running the latest. It's odd that the same script run different ways produces different results. The most likely explanation is that you have two different versions of PHP; one for CLI, one for web. Try running a script containing `phpinfo();` in each to confirm (or run `php -v` on a CLI).

Comment: Thank you. What I mean is that the signature part is completely ignored, so the e-mail is not signed at all. After trying many different things, I realized the issue may be permissions related: my private key folder is within /var/lib/amavis/dkim and it seems my apache user (www-data) can't access it. If I copy the private key file to a website folder (var/www/... obviously not a good idea), everything works in web again. But I did not manage to make www-data access the private key file, not even adding it to the amavis group.

Comment: That’s still unclear. Either it’s signed, but the signature fails to verify, and you will have failure info headers telling you why. Or is the signature header completely absent? Perhaps post the headers of a message received each way in your question?

Comment: The signature header is completely absent. While troubleshooting I checked whether the key file was accessible and added this 
$privatekey = $mail->DKIM_private;
echo $privatekey;
if (file_exists($privatekey))
{
 echo "Have access";
}
else
{
 echo "No access";
}

And, once more, with CLI, it prints Have access but with web No access

Comment: Ok, so you need to sort out ownership and permissions on those files.

Comment: Thank you, Synchro. Unfortunately I am unable to sort it out. Things I have already tried:

1. Add user www-data to group amavis (who owns the folder that contains the private key).
2. Set permissions to 777 to the private key folder (as a desperate attempt).
3. Add symlinks to the public and private keys within website folder (/var/web/site_name/private)

Comment: Well you’re going to have to persevere because we can’t fix it for you. PHPMailer is only doing the simplest of file operations, nothing complex. Check that you don’t have something like SELinux or apparmor preventing file access.

Comment: I added some more details to my question, such as the php script being run and the debug info I get in both cases, just in case it helps. I appreciate all the help provided. Thank you

Comment: Adding the private key to /var/www/mysite/private folder works but not sure how insecure this is...

Comment: It’s fine so long as that’s outside your web root